# Visual Studio Crash on Startup while loading MEF

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I've recently installed Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise. After the first start I connected my microsoft-account to the studio. Now I'm not able to start the visual studio again. During the splash-screen a small loading-window appears which says:

> Scanning new and updated MEF components

And while this window appears the application crashes.

What can I do to fix this?